# Failed Dependencies When Trying to Install OpenOffice

Tags: fedora, openoffice

I'm using Fedora 37. I am new to Linux, and I am not very good with technical Linux terms and advanced commands. I only know the VERY basics. I am trying to install OpenOffice via RPM packages. Here is the command I entered to install the RPMs:

```
sudo rpm -i *.rpm
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
openoffice4.1.13-suse-menus conflicts with openoffice4.1.13-freedesktop-menus-4.1.13-9810.noarch
openoffice4.1.13-redhat-menus conflicts with openoffice4.1.13-freedesktop-menus-4.1.13-9810.noarch
openoffice4.1.13-mandriva-menus conflicts with openoffice4.1.13-freedesktop-menus-4.1.13-9810.noarch
mandrake-release is needed by openoffice4.1.13-mandriva-menus-4.1.13-9810.noarch
redhat-release is needed by openoffice4.1.13-redhat-menus-4.1.13-9810.noarch
/etc/SuSE-release is needed by openoffice4.1.13-suse-menus-4.1.13-9810.noarch
```

I do not know why I have conflicting packages even though I don't have OpenOffice installed. I've tried to remove the conflicting packages, but it just spits out another error I do not understand. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you downloaded a slew of rpms into your current directory with rpms for multiple distributions present. You need to delete any rpms for Suse, Mandriva, or other distributions before you use your wildcard install. Perhaps instructions such as [this](https://explorelinux.com/how-to-install-openoffice-in-fedora-workstation/) will help narrow down the rpm list. LibreOffice is another alternative that might be better supported on your distribution. Available as a snap or an rpm download. Instructions [here](https://www.fosslinux.com/42509/how-to-install-libreoffice-on-fedora.htm).

Comment: @doneal24 those instructions rather miss the point of LibreOffice being supported in the distro...

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice doesn’t have many contributors and sees little development; most of the former OpenOffice contributors work on a fork, LibreOffice. I recommend installing the latter; it is directly supported in most Linux distributions, including Fedora, where it can be installed by running

```
sudo dnf install libreoffice
```